# CSS rule to select pseudo-elements

Tags: css, css-selectors, pseudo-element, adblock

I'm using Brave browser to block ads online. Some sites started injecting ads into HTML on their server side. Brave currently only allows blocking elements by providing a CSS selector.

The element I want to block is a `div` with a randomly-generated class name (so using `div.class-name` works only until refresh). The only constant is a pseudo `::before` element with `content: "from our network"`.

My question is: can I select an element based on the content of its `::before`, without using any JavaScript (CSS only)?

Comment: no you cannot .. but try to see if there is an attribute or some inline styles that are the same, or probably he random class contain a pattern

Comment: You can select a `div` based on its context too... what is the structure that div sits in? Any useful classes you can hook into there?

Comment: No structure I can discern - it's a bunch of nested `div`s. If you select the wrong one, page content is gone.

Comment: @Traveling Tech Guy: If the div always appears n levels deep, you can repeat "> div" from "body" as many times as needed to reach it. If the nesting level is random, then yeah you're pretty much out of luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to select an element base on ::before content?

```
div::after {
  content: "generated content";
}
```

I don't think that's possible

You can however select few characters in the class name

```
div[class^='yourclassname'], div[class*=' yourclassname']{

}
```

https://codepen.io/gilbertlucas46/pen/xBjKOX

Comment: The content is constant - the class name is random. How is selecting few characters in the class name helpful, considering the class name is generated every page refresh?

Comment: @Traveling Tech Guy: Well, Gilbert is probably erring on the side of assuming that at least some part of the randomized class name is constant. But as you and I know, ads tend not to include anything constant in their randomized class names.